# Omitting doctype declaration of an XML when applying XSLT

Tags: c#, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

I have XML files which contains a doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE someName SYSTEM "fileName.dtd">
```

The file is provided by a 3rd party, I have no control over how it is generated.
I use XSLT to transform the XML, but XSLT complains about the dtd not found; how do I tell XSLT to ommit it so it doesn't try to access the dtd file which I don't have.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do it for C#

```
XmlReaderSettings x = new XmlReaderSettings();
x.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
myXslTransform.Load(xslFile);
myXslTransform.Transform(XmlReader.Create(xslFile, x), XmlWriter.Create(xmlFileOutput));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the EntityResolver of the XML parser to an EntityResolver that substitutes a local file (perhaps an empty file) when the DTD is requested. Create an XMLReader (parser) with this setting, then supply a SAXSource containing this XMLReader as the source input to the transformation.

Comment: thanks, I use XslCompiledTransform though, I will check if I can find examples with the EntityResolver for it

Comment: I believe XslCompiledTransform uses an XmlResolver which has a similar purpose to Java's EntityResolver.

Answer (score 0):

Which xslt-processor do you use? You have to find a way to disable validation for it.
E.g. for Java you could do it so: http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200205/post80150.html

The main reason why it's here: the dtd could have default data which affects xml content. E.g. if an attribute "align" has default value "left", the xslt template match "[@align='left']" will match even if attribute is not occurring in an XML.

Comment: Disabling validation won't prevent the DTD being read (or causing a failure if it can't be read): as you explain, the DTD contains information needed by the parser even when not validating.

Comment: So, the only solution is to provide fake DTD or EntityResolver. It was mentioned by the link above.

Comment: @kan: I use XslCompiledTransform in C#